# Using WebView in JavaFX breaks the UI on Linux

Tags: java, linux, javafx, webview

I would like to have a webview component and a button on the stage but when I load a http://mail.google.com in the WebView the other button drawn on the stage gets problems.

After having loaded the page successfully if I hover on the button with the mouse the button itself disappears leaving only its label visible.

The problem is only on Linux since when I tried the same project with Windows it was okay.

The funny story is that if I change the url I want to load with another one, say http://www.google.com the button is not affected by this weird problem.

My Linux 64 bit Mint 17.3 and the Java version is jdk1.8.0_91.
Here is the code, a [video](https://youtu.be/13F8U6vQyoY) and some screenshots of the strange behaviour.

```
package javafxwebviewnofxml;


import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


/**
 *   
 * @author Aldo Marx    
 */
public class JavaFXWebviewNoFXML extends Application {

    public WebEngine webEngine;
    public  String urlToGo;
    public  AnchorPane anchorPane;
    private WebView webView;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
            btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    System.out.println("Hello World my friends!");
                }
            });

            anchorPane = new AnchorPane() ;
            anchorPane.setPrefSize(1160, 900);  

            AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(btn, 900.00);
            AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(btn, 400.00);

            webView = new WebView();
            webView.setPrefSize(1160, 900);
            webEngine = webView.getEngine();
             urlToGo =   "http://mail.google.com";   // this url is not okay 
         //   urlToGo =  " http://facebook.com";      // this url is okay 
         //  urlToGo = "http://www.google.com";   // this url is okay
            webEngine.load(urlToGo); 

            anchorPane.getChildren().addAll(webView);
            anchorPane.getChildren().addAll(btn);

            Scene scene = new Scene(anchorPane, 1160, 900);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
    }




   public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

The button as appears on the stage when it's not hovered by the mouse can be seen here below
[image]

The button as appears on the stage when it is hovered by the mouse (and this is the problem ) can be seen here below
[image]

Comment: I suggest that you change your client secret.  Publishing secrets on the Internet is usually not a good idea.

Comment: Okay, I will remove the fancy URL from the projet all together. I have the same issue with just http://mail.google.com so I don't need a complicated url like that to show this problem. Thanks jewelsea!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by adding -Dprism.order=j2d to VM options.

Answer (score 0):

Don's set layout x, ... when placing in an AnchorPane, use anchoring: AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor and similar

Comment: Done, thanks Milan but unfortunately this does not solve my issue.